# How to prevent Blogger from converting relative URLs to absolute URLs

Tags: html, links, blogger

If you create relative links in Blogger, it tends to automatically convert them into absolute links or to add `http://` in front of the URL.

Is there any way to prevent this?

**Update**: I have reported this to the [Blogger forum as an issue](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/blogger/something-is-broken/YyvIzHuOBdI). Let's hope Google will fix it.

Comment: Maybe http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ would know?

Comment: Not sure if this is still working, but have a look at: [Templates - Making relative links work](http://archives.blogspot.com/#3668266).

Comment: Just out of curiosity... why do you want the links to stay relative?

Comment: Because sometimes, you need to move posts around (import/export them). Or, a blog's url may change. This has an impact on link juice and page rank. There is a <base> tag to solve this, but Blogger breaks it... which forces one to implement redirects, which is more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Have you tried an explicit relative url (./rest/of/url.html)? The post you link to only has the implicit relative url (rest/of/url.html). Or do they process the ./ out as well?

Answer (score 1):

From [your bug report to Google](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/blogger/YyvIzHuOBdI/f9joB5iEh28J), another user nitecruzr posts this helpful advice:

> The only way to avoid this problem is to not switch between "Compose" and "Edit HTML" modes, in Post Editor.  Or plan your post development - and add relative links as the last step before publishing.
>
> http://blogging.nitecruzr.net/2010/07/anchor-links-and-post-editor-compose.html
>
> We reported this, 4 years ago.  Blogger Engineering prefers alternate solutions, apparently.